# Where is the flaw in this proof of Legendre's Conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, open-problem

### **Introduction**

The following argument has been advanced by one of my friends which attempts to prove the [Legendre's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_conjecture). I could find no flaw in the argument and so I am posting it here in the hope that people here will be able to find a flaw in the argument.

> **Theorem.** For all sufficiently large $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have, $$\pi((x+1)^2)-\pi(x^2)>0$$where $\pi(x)$ denotes the number of primes less than or equal to $x$.

*Proof.*
The proof assumes the following facts,

(1) $\pi(x)>\dfrac{x}{\ln x}$ for all $x\ge 17$. (see [this paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#cite_note-19) for details)

(2) For all $\varepsilon>0$ $\dfrac{x}{\ln x-(1-\varepsilon)}<\pi(x)<\dfrac{x}{\ln x-(1+\varepsilon)}$ for all $x\ge \max\left(227,\exp(\frac{1.51}{\varepsilon})\right)$. (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019621/is-there-any-general-method-of-finding-the-lower-bound-of-x-that-satisfy-the-i/1032908#1032908))

We will show that $\pi((x+1)^2)-\pi(x^2)>0$ for all sufficiently large real $x$. For this observe that, for all sufficiently large $x\in\mathbb{R}$  we have, \begin{align}\pi(x^2)<\dfrac{x^2}{2(\ln x-2)}\end{align} (which follows from (2) by chosing $\varepsilon=3$) and $$\pi((x+1)^2)>\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{2\ln (x+1)}$$by (1). So we have, \begin{align}\pi((x+1)^2)-\pi(x^2)&>\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{2\ln (x+1)}-\dfrac{x^2}{2(\ln x-2)}\end{align}
To prove the conjecture it suffices to show that,
 $$\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{2\ln (x+1)}>\dfrac{x^2}{2(\ln x-2)}$$ To prove which it suffices to show that, $$\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{2(\ln (x+1)-2)}\dfrac{2\ln(x+1)-4}{\ln (x+1)}>\dfrac{x^2}{2(\ln x-2)}$$Which holds for all sufficiently large $x$. So we are done.

### **Question**

What is(are) the flaw(s) in the proof? I am sure that there must be some because if the argument were this easy, it would have been proved much earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, from the second last line to the last line you go from

$$\frac{(x+1)^2}{2 \ln(x+1)} >^{?}  \frac{x^2}{2 (\ln(x) - 1)} $$

and then you multiply the numerator and denominator of the LHS by $2 (\ln(x+1) - 2) = 2 \ln(x+1) - 4$ to get

$$\frac{(x+1)^2}{2 (\ln(x+1) - 2)} \frac{2 \ln(x+1) - 4}{2 \ln(x+1)} >^{?}  \frac{x^2}{2 (\ln(x) - 1)} $$

and then, for some unknown reason, you multiply the LHS by a factor of $2$ to get

$$\frac{(x+1)^2}{2 (\ln(x+1) - 2)} \frac{2 \ln(x+1) - 4}{ \ln(x+1)} >  \frac{x^2}{2 (\ln(x) - 1)} $$

So yeah, the last inequality holds (for large $x$) but not the previous two inequalities, because you left out the factor of $2$ in $2 \ln(x+1)$. In fact, the first two (equivalent) inequalities just completely fail, so all this argument proves is the slightly less impressive inequality

$$\pi((x+1)^2) - \pi(x^2) \ge \text{some negative number}$$

which it turns out in fact can be deduced via more direct methods.